# TypeScript - Why I cannot push value to a string after I have defined the array type to number[] | string[]

Tags: typescript

I get an error as below

`Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

And the error is at `alarm[key]`

Here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import alarmData from '../../mockData/alarmdData.json';

interface IAlarm {
  createdTime: string;
  station: string;
  deviceID: string;
  category: string;
  alarmValue: number;
  alarmType: string;
  status: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  handleState: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AlarmDataService {
  setColumnData(key: string, array: number[] | string[]): void {
    alarmData.forEach((alarm: IAlarm) => array.push(alarm[key]));
  }

  logData() {
    console.log(alarmData);
  }
}
```

My json file content is below:

```
[
  {
    "createdTime": "2022/03/24 18:00",
    "station": "testStation",
    "deviceID": "S1001",
    "category": "SO2",
    "alarmValue": 33,
    "alarmType": "SO2 limit",
    "status": "alarm",
    "startTime": "2022/03/24 18:00",
    "endTime": "2022/03/24 19:00",
    "handleState": "handled"
  },
  {
    "createdTime": "2022/03/24 19:00",
    "station": "test1Station",
    "deviceID": "S1002",
    "category": "NO",
    "alarmValue": 33,
    "alarmType": "NO limit",
    "status": "alarm",
    "startTime": "2022/03/24 20:00",
    "endTime": "2022/03/24 21:00",
    "handleState": "handled"
  }
]
```

Why I get this hint 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IAlarm'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IAlarm'.'.

What should I do to debug my code? Thank you for helping me in advance.

I have tried to change the array to 'any' but it still does not work.

Comment: There are at least two problems here. The first one is trying to get a property with an arbitrary string. TS does not know which property (if any) you'd get and thus cannot guarantee type safety. Second the array being declared as only either numbers or strings, means that you can only add one or the other. There is no guarantee whether you got an array of numbers and you're trying to push a string into it or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read your code, it seems like the intent of the `setColumnData` function is as follows:

> Given a property defined on the `IAlarm` interface and an array of `IAlarm` objects, extract the value of this property from each of those objects, and put all these values into a single array.

With that in mind, this should work:

```
setColumnData<Key extends keyof IAlarm>(key: Key, array: IAlarm[Key][]): void {
    alarmData.forEach((alarm) => array.push(alarm[key]));
}
```

Some notes:

- By using `Key extends keyof IAlarm`, we ensure that the `key` parameter can only be one of the properties of `IAlarm` (e.g. `station` or `category`). Any other values will cause a type error.
- Using `IAlarm[Key][]` as the type of the `array` parameter ensures that the type of the values in the array matches that of the property on `IAlarm` (`number` for `alarmValue`, `string` for anything else). This has the benefit of supporting additional types without requiring modifications to this method (for example, if you were to add a `boolean` property to `IAlarm`).

Here is [a simplified version of this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEA2coFtkDeAUMsglBHJACYAqwuEAXMgM5hSgDmA3CW2CrAA9iBbtOIXv2oQAbsCSoAIuI7c%20pBFQhdhUAJ5rJ00nGx4AauYCuzZCBu4ARtE3JzOXLQMAHexIa-OxUNqzGQaQhUGD0jBFS7hAgdAwB6on8ABZwKZgQAMqCkAnSAL5ERAii7B4WuMpUcCwY9QDaALrIALzInZUQAB6%20%20mBk2KysyFhejYIF0ApIhMEQYADCwphOIHNwADwA0hAGyEOQKVMA1ifCMGgzeAB8ABQ3RsjHBgA0HlBQcA%20rS8bS%20HU6AEoWHJhMBqCtSGZ6nsAHQwfQAUUQWReL08eAhPSefwBBhRvjCOPxuDa7w6EIh7gqZSAA) on the TS Playground.